# AWS QuickSight: Counting values in a column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have the following entries in a dataset:

```
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
a
b
a
```

How can I count the number of occurrences for each value?

In Excel, if this list were on column A, I would use the formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
=COUNTIF(A:A,A3)
...
```

and I would get the following:

```
a: 4
b: 3
c: 2
d: 1
a: 4
b: 3
c: 2
a: 4
b: 3
a: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

If the column name is "col1":

```
countIf({col1}, {col1} = {col1})
```